# Compilation error while adding mp-olsr on ns 2.34 (Jiazi YI ns 2.29)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, protocols, ns2

I'm trying to add the mp-olsr(ns 2.29) into ns 2.34 and I'm getting some errors while compiling it.

Source code(Jiazi YI): http://www.jiaziyi.com/index.php/research-projects/mp-olsr

Procedure:

> $ touch common/packet.cc
>   $ make

Result:

> mpolsr/MPOLSR.o: In function `MPOLSR::MPOLSR(int)':
>
>   MPOLSR.cc:(.text+0x1457): undefined reference to`Agent::Agent(packet_t)'
>   mpolsr/MPOLSR.o: In function `MPOLSR::MPOLSR(int)':
>
>   MPOLSR.cc:(.text+0x16f1): undefined reference to`Agent::Agent(packet_t)'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: ** [ns] Erro 1

What could I have missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve my error I modified the following in MPOLSR.cc:

From:

> `MPOLSR::MPOLSR(nsaddr_t id) : Agent(PT_MPOLSR),`
>   `hello_timer_(this),`
>   `tc_timer_(this),`
>   `mid_timer_(this) {`

To(everything on a single line):

> `MPOLSR::MPOLSR(nsaddr_t id) : Agent(PT_MPOLSR), hello_timer_(this),tc_timer_(this),   mid_timer_(this) {`

I know it sounds silly, but it resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Before add the new protocol you need to add your protocol name into common/packet.h file
after that add your xxx.o \ into Makefile than enter make command in your terminal window..

What you have done is not correct.

Comment: I already have done this. I've modified packet.h and all places that need to be modified, then I added to the make the xxx.o \

Comment: error collect2: ld returned 1 exit status is denotes there is no error in your c++ code.the error is in your configuration  only..

Comment: I implemented another protocol before, I just followed the same steps. Something isn't right, I just can't figure it out what it is wrong.